# Change Flash alert in cakePHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cakephp

So normally the: `$this->Session->setFlash(__('Email deleted successfully'));`

would render out:

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="message">
    Email deleted successfully
</div>
```

How could I get this to display:

```
$.growl.error({ message: "Email delted successfully" });
```

The above is using javascript and a library called jQuery Growl. I have already placed all the necessary CSS and JS in the default layout of cakephp.

I would assume you would have to edit: `app/view/layouts/flash.ctp` But I tried replacing the current code:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $message; ?></a></p>
```

With but I had no luck. The javascript did not even display out in the `inspect element` of chrome.

```
<script>    
   $.growl.error({ message: "Email delted successfully" });
</script>
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your custom stuff in an element per the book:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages

> The $element parameter allows you to control which element (located in
>   /app/View/Elements) should be used to render the message in. In the
>   element the message is available as $message. First we set the flash
>   in our controller:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Something custom!', 'flash_custom');
```